# Alteryx REGEX upper first letter of every sentence and lower case for the rest

Tags: regex, alteryx

I'm trying to transform strings in Alteryx using one regex tool as follows

Original:

```
lorem ipsum. DOLOR SIT AMET.
```

Looking for:

```
Lorem ipsum. Dolor sit amet.
```

Now, I did manage to match this pattern with the following REGEX

```
(^\w)|\.\s(\w)
```

But I'm not sure how to replace it in Alteryx.

Any ideas? I expected `\U$1\U$2` and copy unmatched to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following, written with your shown samples. This is creating 4th capturing groups, where 1st capturing will have like: `D`, 2nd capturing group contains `OLOR`, 3rd capturing group contains `SIT` and 4th capturing group contains `AMET` in shown samples.

```
^.*?\.\s+(.)(.*?)\s+(.*?)\s+([^.]*)\.$
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/oRJTHM/4)

So you could try following command: `$1 \U$2 \U$3 \U$4`